# Restore a Database Programatically (SQL Server)

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, backup, database-restore

I recently found this [link](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial180_Backup-and-restore-SQL-databases.html) which shows a great example of backing up and restoring a sql server database. However, my SQL Server only uses WindowsAuthentication and so it does not really require a UserName and Password. To be able to do this, I turned the line `srvConn.LoginSecure = false;` into `srvConn.LoginSecure = true;`

I was expecting to connect succesfully to the Server. However, this example returns an exception saying that it was unable to connect to the server.

Can anybody help me please? I have to learn this application for me to be able to apply the same concept to a project i'm working on. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is your application running on the same PC as the SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to enable remote connection to your server (I'm not sure if this is what you're after), Try this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277 . You will also want to make sure the mixed authentication option is enabled.